# Inverse Transform with FunctionTransformer from sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I wanted to create my own Transformer using scikit-learn FunctionTransformer and followed their example as a dry run. It worked, but then I wanted to take the inverse of that transformation just to see the end result. However, when I tried the inverse_transform, it returned the same thing as the transformation. How do I get the original values? I ask this because I plan on using this transformation to transform a target variable, then make predictions. Those predictions will need be inversely transformed after I predict.

As a side bar, should I fit on y_train and transform on my y_test? Or can I transform y all at once?

My transformer:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer
import random
randomlist = []
for i in range(0,100):
    n = random.randint(1,100)
    randomlist.append(n)
y = pd.Series(randomlist)
y_train = y[:80]
y_test = y[80:]
target_trans = FunctionTransformer(np.log, validate=True, check_inverse = True)
logy_train = target_trans.fit_transform(y_train.values.reshape(-1,1))
logy_test = target_trans.transform(y_test.values.reshape(-1,1))
target_trans.inverse_transform(y_train.values.reshape(-1,1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within `FunctionTransformer()` you not only need to define `check_inverse=True` but also define the actual inverse function itself.

So for the above,

```
target_trans = FunctionTransformer(np.log, inverse_func = np.exp
                                   ,validate=True, check_inverse = True)
```

which yields the desired result.

Comment: How we can set parameters for inverse function? E.g. we want to inverse the normalization with Mean and and std.

Comment: sklearn has built in standardization and normalization methods you can call, with their own inverses built in.